# Combine blacktriangle and blacktriangledown

Tags: arrows, stacking-symbols

I need to combine `\blacktriangle` and `\blacktriangledown` so that I get the following result: [image: Up Down Arrow]

I already tried `$\stackrel{\blacktriangle}{\blacktriangledown}$` but then the triangle pointing up is bigger than the one pointing down.

The combined symbols should have the same line height as my text, because I need a list like this (here the triangles are a little bit too big)

[image: Up Down Arrow] XXX
[image: Up Down Arrow] XXX
[image: Up Down Arrow] XXX

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us to help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: `\stackunder{}{}` from `stackengine` could be a solution, replacing `\blacktriangle` with `\blacktriangleup`

Comment: There are many possibilities. One is `$\substack{\blacktriangle \\ \blacktriangledown}$` from the `amsmath` package.

Comment: @ChristianHupfer Oh, sorry. Will add a MWE for the next question. Thanks anyways!!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The following examples stacks the symbols and scales them to fit the line height:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{calc}

\newcommand*{\textdoubletriangle}{%
  \resizebox{!}{\heightof{X}}{%
    \vbox{%
      \hbox{$\blacktriangle$}%
      \nointerlineskip
      \kern.75ex
      \hbox{$\blacktriangledown$}%
    }%
  }%
}

\begin{document}
\textdoubletriangle XXX
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]

Answer (score 8):

You were actually quite close with the idea

```
\stackrel{\blacktriangle}{\blacktriangledown}
```

To overcome the problem of the upper symbol being smaller than the lower one, all one needs to do is to insert `\textstyle` at the beginning of the first argument of `\stackrel`. To center the resulting symbol vertically on the math axis, you could place the instructions in a `\vcenter{\hbox{$` ... `$}}` wrapper:

```
\newcommand\bigblacktriangleupdown{%
    \vcenter{\hbox{$\stackrel{\textstyle\blacktriangle}{\blacktriangledown}$}}}
```

Medium and small versions of the same construct could be defined via

```
\newcommand\mediumblacktriangleupdown{%
    \vcenter{\hbox{$\stackrel{\blacktriangle}{\scriptstyle\blacktriangledown}$}}}

\newcommand\smallblacktriangleupdown{%
    \vcenter{\hbox{$\stackrel{\scriptscriptstyle\blacktriangle}{%
                              \scriptscriptstyle\blacktriangledown}$}}}
```

This is what the three symbols look like:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amssymb}

\newcommand\bigblacktriangleupdown{%
    \vcenter{\hbox{$\stackrel{\textstyle\blacktriangle}{\blacktriangledown}$}}}

\newcommand\mediumblacktriangleupdown{%
    \vcenter{\hbox{$\stackrel{\blacktriangle}{\scriptstyle\blacktriangledown}$}}}

\newcommand\smallblacktriangleupdown{%
    \vcenter{\hbox{$\stackrel{\scriptscriptstyle\blacktriangle}{\scriptscriptstyle\blacktriangledown}$}}}

\begin{document}
$\bigblacktriangleupdown$ XXXX

$\mediumblacktriangleupdown$ XXXX

$\smallblacktriangleupdown$ XXXX
\end{document}
```

If you don't want these symbols centered vertically on the math axis and, instead, want their lower tips to "rest" on the baseline, just leave off the `\vcenter{\hbox{$` ... `$}}` wrappers.

Answer (score 6):

Here is an alternative using the `stackengine` package.

[image]

```
\documentclass[letterpaper]{article}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{stackengine}
\usepackage{calc}

\newcommand{\updowntriangle}{%
    \resizebox{!}{\heightof{X}}{%
    \stackMath\Shortstack[c]{%
        {\blacktriangle}
        \blacktriangledown}%
    }%
}
\begin{document}
\updowntriangle XXXX
\end{document}
```